# slow network performance samba

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, samba

[image: screenshot]
I'm suffering from poor network performance on my PI.

I use samba to copy files from W7 to an external 3,5inch usb3 drive, NTFS formatted and mounted on the pi using NTFS (not the 3g).

I have seen a lot of reports of slow networking with samba but not many fixes.

After upgrading my firmware the speed dropped from 3.xx MB/s to 2.7x MB/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIFS is a slower protocol to start with, and 27/30Mbps isn't terrible.  The usual fix is to change over to something like NFS or rsync (or even SFTP/SCP).  Overclocking might help if it's safe for you to do so.

Comment: Is it normal to have only 30mbps over a LAN network?
I did notice a small improvement with a small overclock so I guess it's very CPU intensive...

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense that overclocking would improve the rate.  NFS (without Kerberos) doesn't have much overhead to it as it's a really simple protocol without encryption.  CIFS is more complex and SFTP/SCP uses the encryption in SSH to transfer files, but you can sometimes use a faster and less secure encryption method to boost performance.  30mbps on a 100mbps LAN isn't great, but it's not terrible either.

Comment: I now use the pre set 'turbo' OC mode (1GHz)
That seems to pull up the transfer speeds to an acceptable level.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge all the PI uses USB 2.0 technology which means that you are limited by the tech here. i believe that USB 2.0 cab achieve speed around 5MB/s. So be glad that you are able to pull out the transfer speed you are getting.

I have A PINAS as well but get speed in the KB/s when transferring data to the PI